# How to categorize incoming emails

Tags: email, mutt, imap

I have a Gmail account, mutt is configured to get the mail through IMAP. Yesterday I subscribed to a mailing list and now my personal emails are mixed up with the ones from the list.

The list emails are addressed to me and lilypond-user@gnu.org. How can I tell mutt to move all such emails to a separate file, so they wouldn't be mixed with my emails. But I still could read them, opening that file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options depending on what you are wanting to achieve and what you are wanting to do to get there.

- Get the IMAP server to do the filtering for you.

  This is sometimes an option in web-mail based solutions and allows you to filter the messages based on e.g. the addresses listed in the `To:` or `Cc:` header of each mail. I'm not familiar with Gmail's offerings in this regard.
- Manually mark the messages in `mutt` and copy them to a new folder on the IMAP server, or to a local mailbox.

  Mark the messages you want to move with <kbd>T</kbd> followed by the search pattern `~C lilypond-user@gnu.org` (this tags all messages that were either sent directly to or Cc-ed to the address `lilypond-user@gnu.org`).  Then press <kbd>;</kbd> followed by <kbd>s</kbd> to apply the "save" (move) command to all tagged messages. Then enter the IMAP folder path you want to save the messages to.

  The IMAP folder path should be specified as

  ```
  imap[s]:[user[:pw]@]imapserver.example.com[:port]/path
  ```

  Just to say that the IMAP server that I have access to doesn't like this.  There are no errors, but the messages are clearly not copied. Test it on a less important message first! You may obviously save the messages locally instead!

  You may also define a macro in `mutt` to do this.
- Download the messages from the IMAP server and filter and read them locally.

I tend to download the messages off the IMAP server using `fetchmail`.  This gives me the opportunity to do my own spam filtering and mail sorting on my local machine.

For both these tasks I use `procmail`<sup>1</sup> which is a fairly advanced mail processing program.

The essential configuration for `fetchmail` that I use is

```
poll myimapserver.example.com
    protocol imap
    user "myimapusername" password "myimappassword" is "mylocalusername"
    mda "/usr/local/bin/procmail -m $HOME/.procmailrc"
    ssl sslcertfile /etc/ssl/cert.pem sslcertck
    idle
```

This will fetch any new messages off the IMAP server as they arrive, and deliver them to `procmail` for processing.  Paths etc. will be different on your system.

Then I filter with `procmail` using a configuration (`$HOME/.procmailrc`) like

```
MAILDIR="$HOME/Mail"
DEFAULT="inbox/"

:0
* ^TO_announce@openbsd.org
openbsd-announce/

:0
* ^TO_misc@openbsd.org
openbsd-misc/
```

... for two of the mailing lists I'm on (they will be stored in subdirectories under `$HOME/Mail`). Mail not matching any patterns will be stored in `$HOME/Mail/inbox` as specified by `MAILDIR` and `DEFAULT`.  I'm using Maildir mailboxes.  Remove the trailing slashes on the paths to get mbox mailboxes.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that [`procmail` is retired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail).  I was not aware of this as I've been using is since the 90's without much consideration for any of the up-and-coming alternatives.  It seems, after some gentle browsing on the interwebs, that `maildrop` is considered a good alternative to `procmail`, and I might look into moving my filtering over to `maildrop` myself.</sub>

Comment: Please note that `procmail` has been unmaintained for 10+ years.  Its last hard-core proponents deserted it a few years ago (I was there when it happened, so I should know). :) It has well-known security vulnerabilities.  __And__ there are better alternatives to it these days.  There is no reason to suggest it to new users.

Comment: @SatoKatsura As a `procmail` user since the 90's, I'm less likely to change, given that there is a maintained port on my Unix.  However, that also means I'm unaware of the alternatives. Maybe you can give a good example of a well established mail processing tool that would fill `procmail`'s void?

Comment: The main contenders seem to be [fdm](https://github.com/nicm/fdm) and [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) (I personally prefer `fdm`). Don't know about them being well-established. There's the usual pressure for people to abandon mail in favor of other, presumably easier to track systems. So the landscape of MDAs is already badly skewed.